# How to loop through component names?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to display all the component names I imported to my XYZ View (and display it in `cards`). I need to somehow store component names in `data` property as to loop through it in `template` later. I tried to refer to `components` property from within `data` property using `this.components` but it doesn't work.
I don't want to use `names: ['A', 'B', 'C']` in `data` and loop through it, it's not a smart and efficient way even though this solution works. How can I get component names then?

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col
        v-for="(comp, n) in names"
        :key="n"
        :cols="n === 0 ? 2 : 10"
        >
        
          <v-card outlined tile>
            <component :is="comp"></component>
          </v-card>

      </v-col>

    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import A from '../views/A.vue';
import B from '../views/B.vue';
import C from '../views/C.vue';

export default {
  name: 'XYZ',
  data() {
    return {
      names: this.components,
      // names: ['A', 'B', 'C']   // I don't want to make it this way even though it works fine
    }
  },
  components: {
    A,
    B,
    C
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.$options.components` - [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)

```js
const componentA = {
  name: 'compA',
  template: `<h3>Hi from compA</h3>`
}

const componentB = {
  name: 'compB',
  template: `<h3>Hi from compB</h3>`
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    componentA,
    componentB
  },
  data() {    
    return {
      // do this if you want names by which the components are (locally) registered
      // this is much more usefull as you can use these names with <component :is="name">
      componentNames1: Object.keys(this.$options.components),
      
      // do this if you want names defined in components definition
      componentNames2: Object.entries(this.$options.components).map(entry => entry[1].name)      
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>1: {{ componentNames1 }}</div>
<div>2: {{ componentNames2 }}</div>
<hr>
<div v-for="name in componentNames1">
  <component :is="name" :key="name"></component>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your solution. One more question - can I loop through those names then? As I showed in my example (template section)? In my real app I need to insert each component into separate column, that's why I need to loop though it. And I can't with this solution. I EDITED my question adding columns section.

Comment: Of course you can - just use the 1st set of names (names by which components are registered). Check my updated example

Comment: How to get 'this.$options.name' in vue 3 ?

Comment: @hyphens2 In Vue 3 [$options is still available](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#options) so you can use it same way as in Vue 2. If you mean how to use it from Composition API (`setup` hook) I don't think it is possible

Comment: @MichalLevý Thanks, I'm using composition api with vue 3 and can't find anyway to get component name like this